# how to get previous transaction history for a particular address web3js1.0.0

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js-v1.x

```
web3.eth.getPastLogs({
    fromBlock : 3150168,
    toBlock : 3153168,
    address: "0xAD08C190Ed643ec60afBbAEB2E284F616F3C3b43",
    topics: [topics]
})
.then(result=>{})
.catch(error=>{})
```

how to define topics parameter?

Answer (score 0):

> topics - Array: An array of values which must each appear in the log entries. The order is important, if you want to leave topics out use null, e.g. [null, '0x12...']. You can also pass an array for each topic with options for that topic e.g. [null, ['option1', 'option2']]

Source - https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs

e.g. `topics: ["0x033456732123ffff2342342dd12342434324234234fd234fd23fd4f23d4234"]`

In order to calculate topic you need to generate SHA3 from event signature, looks like:

```
const transfer = web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");
```

Comment: thanks for responding but i want to get ether transaction history not the token

Comment: @rahulsaini I think it is not possible with `getPastLogs`. In order to do this, you need to explore whole chain

Comment: hi @Aquila i also found the same i tried getPastLogs and subscribe method but did not get anything for ether transaction

Comment: I mean you need to explore chain by your own